# How to dynamically INSERT a COLUMN value?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like Table1 with a few records in it. I'm trying to insert records to Table2 using this query `INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1, 'Orange', (SELECT ID FROM Table1));` I'd like to INSERT the ID from Table1 one after the other to Table2 having all the other values static.

```
**Table1**

ID     Name     
1      Round
2      Edible
3      Blue
4      Seeds
```

---

```
**Table2**

ID     Name     Table1ID
1      Orange      1
2      Orange      2
3      Orange      4
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to INSERT the ID from Table1 one after the other to Table2 having all the other values static.

Use the static values as part of the `SELECT` query from `Table1`

```
INSERT INTO Table2 
SELECT 1, 'Orange', ID FROM Table1
```

This works as long as the columns match up. Sometimes the columns aren't quite the same, and you won't have values for everything in `Table2`. In that case, you can still specify a column list; the trick is not using the `VALUES` keyword.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 
    (ID, Table1ID)
SELECT 0, ID FROM Table1
```

Now, the `Name` field in `Table2` will end up with `NULL` in each new row.

Finally, it's possible you want to create the sequential "1,2,3" ID values from the sample data. There are two ways to do this.

The first way is if this field is the **identity** field in `Table2`. In that case, don't use anything for the new ID column at all:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 
    (Name, Table1ID)
SELECT 'Orange', ID FROM Table1
```

The other option is using the `row_number()` function:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 
SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY ID), 'Orange', ID FROM Table1
```

Comment: From using the row number technique, I got these errors. 

_Invalid column name 'Id'_.

_An explicit value for the identity column in table 'SMSScreenMaster' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON_.

Comment: Then use the other example, and let SQL server worry about exact Id values.

Comment: Using this query `INSERT INTO Table2 (Name, Table1ID)
SELECT 'Orange', ID FROM Table1` It says _Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression_.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. You can't combine `VALUES` and `SELECT` in your `INSERT` you have to choose one or the other. In this case:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT 'Two', 0, NULL, ID FROM Table1;
```

Comment: I got this error _Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression_

Comment: There is no subquery here and there is no use of any of those operators. What does your full SQL look like?